# Rewrite nginx cut last location

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the following URL `http://example.net/bar/foo` to `http://example.net/bar`.

Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
location /bar {
    rewrite ^/bar/(.*)/[^/]+$ /bar/$1;
}
```